# Issue with FOR loops and IF statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, for-loop, repeat

Trying to display # of each combo ordered and total price. Not sure why it won't store values in A, B, and C.  Novice programmer here, so be easy. Been having the problem with if statements for a while, so obviously I'm doing the whole if statement thing incorrectly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
 int group = 0;
 char combo = ' ';
 int A = 0;
 int B = 0;
 int C = 0;
 double total = 0.0;
 cout << "How many customers are in the group? ";
 cin >> group;
 for (int counter = 0; counter < group; counter = counter + 1)
 {
    cout << "Enter combo ordered: ";
    cin >> combo;
    if (combo = A)
    {
        A = A + 1;
        cout << "Enter combo ordered: ";
        cin >> combo;
    }
    else if (combo = B)
    {
        B = B + 1;
        cout << "Enter combo ordered: ";
        cin >> combo;
    }
    else if (combo = C)
    {
        C = C + 1;
        cout << "Enter combo ordered: ";
        cin >> combo;
    }
    total = A*6 + B*6.25 + C*5.75;
 }
 cout << "# of Combo A ordered: " << A << endl;
 cout << "# of Combo B ordered: " << B << endl;
 cout << "# of Combo C ordered: " << C << endl;
 cout << "Total price: $" << total << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to tweak just a few things; a few compilers don't like it when you compute a `double` using `int` and there is no reason to not use `double` here since the program is small. Also a few syntax errors (i.e. with `=` instead of `==`). Have you tried displaying your output in an isolated way? Something like:

```
main(){
double A = 1;
double B = 2;
double C = 3;
double total = A*6 + B*6.25 + C*5.75;

 cout << "# of Combo A ordered: " << A << endl;
 cout << "# of Combo B ordered: " << B << endl;
 cout << "# of Combo C ordered: " << C << endl;
 cout << "Total price: $" << total << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Your corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
 int group = 0;
 char combo = ' ';
 double A = 0;
 double B = 0;
 double C = 0;
 double total = 0.0;
 cout << "How many customers are in the group? ";
 cin >> group;
 for (int counter = 0; counter < group; counter++)
 {
    cout << "Enter combo ordered: ";
    cin >> combo;
    if (combo == 'A')
    {
        A++;
    }
    else if (combo == 'B')
    {
        B++;
    }
    else if (combo == 'C')
    {
        C++;
    } 
    cout << "Enter combo ordered: ";
    cin >> combo;       
 }

 total = A*6 + B*6.25 + C*5.75;

 cout << "# of Combo A ordered: " << A << endl;
 cout << "# of Combo B ordered: " << B << endl;
 cout << "# of Combo C ordered: " << C << endl;
 cout << "Total price: $" << total << endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

I would also display your value for `group` to make sure that the `if` loop is even running at least once. There are a few fault points here that I would test individually.

---

**EDIT:**

Maybe test this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
 int group = 0;
 cout << "How many customers are in the group? ";
 cin >> group;
 for (int counter = 0; counter < group; counter++)
 {
    cout << "Test success";
 }
```

to see if you are even entering into your `for` loop.

Comment: I ran this code and still got nothing but zeros for all quantities

Comment: Ok, now I changed the if to if (combo == 'x') for a b and c and it sort of works, except when I enter 4 for group #, instead of repeating the loop 4 times, it doubles the # of loops

Comment: That is a strange error, I can't really suggest a fix for that. But at least the body of the code is working. I should have noticed that you were entering strings. I overlooked that.

Comment: also, it seems to not count the # of each order correctly.  for example, if I put in A B A C it will say only 2 A's were entered and 0 for B and C

Comment: So, when I put '' around the letters in the IF statement it doubles the loop for some reason and counts in some weird sequence and if I take away the ' ' around the letter in the IF statement, it runs the proper amount of loops, but doesnt count any of the letters

Comment: try the latter, but move the cin, cout part to the bottom of the loop (I did that in the code in my answer).

Comment: Im not sure I know what youre asking

Comment: You have `cout << "Enter combo ordered: ";
        cin >> combo;` in each `if` and `elseif` block. Move that out to the bottom instead. In my answer I wrote "Your corrected code" and then put in the code. I changed that section to reflect what I am saying now.

Comment: Ok, I got it.  I took out all but the first cout << "Enter combo ordered, cin >> combo and it worked fine.

Comment: I moved it to the bottom and it still ran double the group # of loops.  Taking it out everywhere but at the top is what worked.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No problemo :) Make sure you marked the problem as solved for future viewers :)

Comment: Right under where you upvote a question or answer there is a check mark. Click it and it will turn green :)

Answer (score 3):

For-loop should be `for (int counter = 0; counter < group; counter++)`

If statement should use `==` for equality.  `=` is for assignment only.

Your `if` statement needs to quote the character you are comparing: `if (combo == 'A') {`.  It is also possible that you'll need to access combo as an array of characters, like so: `if (combo[0] == 'A') {`

Comment: ok, I fixed those things but it still displays 0 for every display quantity

Comment: I added a few possible fixes for you.